# SQL: Aggregate after join with null check

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these tables (in SQL-Server 2008 R2):

Table1:

```
Id   Guid
1    {530D8FE1-7541-43CC-9F92-1AA776490155}
2    {CAC5B001-C8DE-46AA-A848-5D831633D0DF}
3    NULL
```

Table2:

```
Id    Column1    Table2FK
1     1          1
2     1          2
3     1          3
```

I want to execute a query that aggregates over `Table2.Column1` and joining it to the `Table1` row with the maximum Id, but containing a non-null value for `Table1.Guid`. In this case it should join on row 2 of Table1. Written as a query I want something like this (although this is not valid sql):

```
select t2.Id, t2.Column1, t2.Table2FK, max(t1.Id), t1.Guid 
    from Table2 t2
    join Table1 t1 on t2.Table2FK = t1.Id 
    where t1.Guid is not null
    group by t2.Column1
```

I have managed to do the null-check and the aggregate over `Table2.Id2` separately, but not both in the same query. In the first case the join returns 2 rows, in the second case it joins on row 3 of `Table1`.

Comment: you have not specified what you columns actually expect in the output resultset

Comment: The ones I put in the select clause (basically all of them)

Comment: isn't table2fk a foreign key referencing id in table1? if yes, why would you want both of them listed in the result..I would suggest to think over a little more into the problem and refine you problem statement to get better responses

Comment: @Aadith Yes table2fk is a foreign key to table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an outer join to match rows with a non-null guid.  Then `row_number` can give each found row a "rank", so the highest Column1 will have rank 1:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by t2.Column1, 
                    order by t2.id desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Table2 t2
        left join    
                Table1 t1
        on      t2.Table2FK = t1.id
                and t1.guid is not null
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

The subquery is required because SQL Server does not allow `row_number` directly in a `where` clause.

Comment: I think you switched `Table1` and `Table2` in your answer. If I switch them back I almost get the result I want, but it returns 2 rows because it joins the first 2 rows of of both tables and I want it to return the joined result of the second tow of `Table1` and the second row of `Table2` (i.e. the max `Id` of `Table1` where `Guid` `is not null` grouped by `Column1` of `Table1`).

Comment: @Rian Schmits: You could partition on `Column1` instead of `id`, edited in the answer.